# Can we add "User defined Datatype" + "Predefined Data Type" Using Operator Overloading in c++

Tags: c++

Let us say My class contain object t1. I have to add 5 along with t1.
cout<<5+t1
Please post an example which satisfies the above conditions.

Comment: I think the question is pretty straight forward, but you'll get better answers if you provide a more complete example.

Comment: t1 is a variable in your class.  What type is it?  What is the result of t1+5?  Is it the same type as t1's type?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a type `MyClass` you can provide an `operator+` for it and int like so:

```
MyClass operator+(MyClass lhs, int rhs) {
  return /* ... */ ;
}
```

Though you want to make it commutative so add one with the reverse order as well

```
MyClass operator+(int lhs, MyClass rhs) {
    return rhs + lhs;
}
```

As a complete example:

```
#include <iostream>


struct MyClass {
  int value = 0;
};

MyClass operator+(MyClass lhs, int rhs) {
  lhs.value += rhs;
  return lhs;
}

MyClass operator+(int lhs, MyClass rhs) {
  return rhs + lhs;
}

int main() {
  MyClass mc{3};
  auto result = mc + 5;
  std::cout << result.value << '\n';
}
```

And at this point it's usually benefical to have a `+=` as well. It's easy to implement `+` in terms of `+=`

```
MyClass& operator+=(MyClass& lhs, int rhs) {
  lhs.value += rhs;
  return lhs;
}

MyClass operator+(MyClass lhs, int rhs) {
  lhs += rhs;
  return lhs;
}

MyClass operator+(int lhs, MyClass rhs) {
  return rhs + lhs;
}
```